# SWFOBJECT CurrentFrame Javascript

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I am having a challenge getting the current frame playing.  I am using swfobject ver 2.2.

Here is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function flashplayer(flashname) {

            var flashvars = {};
            var params = {};
            params.play = "true";
            params.menu = "true";
            params.scale = "noscale";
            params.allowfullscreen = "true";
            var attributes = {
                id: "flashDiv",
                name: "flashDiv"
            };
            swfobject.embedSWF(flashname, "myAlternativeContent", "800", "600", "9.0.0", flashvars, params, attributes);
            var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("myAlternativeContent");
            totalFrames = obj.totalFrames;
            $('#duration').html(totalFrames);
            currentFrame1 = obj.currentFrame;
            $('#current').html(currentFrame1);
            obj.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
        }
        function onStateChange() {
            var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("myAlternativeContent");
            currentFrame1 = obj.TcurrentFrame;
            $('#current').html(currentFrame1);
        }
        function stopflash() {
            var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("myAlternativeContent");
            obj.Stop();
        }
        function PlayFlash() {
            var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("myAlternativeContent");
            obj.Play();
        }
        function FlashRewind() {
            var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("myAlternativeContent");
            obj.Rewind();
        }
    </script>

   <div id="duration">
        1
    </div>
    <div id="current">
        1
    </div>
    <input onclick="flashplayer('../../Video/test.swf');" type="button" style="width: 300px"
        value="play flash" /><br />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a quick glance, I see three problems with your code.

1. By specifying an ID and name in your attributes object, you're assinging a name to the newly created `<object>`. This means `swfobject.getObjectById("myAlternativeContent")` won't work, because you've renamed the `<object>` to "flashDiv". You should use `swfobject.getObjectById("flashDiv")` instead.
2. You're trying to use `swfobject.getObjectById` immediately after `swfobject.embedSWF`. However this probably won't work, because the embed might not be completed before `swfobject.getObjectById` is invoked. (BTW, `getObjectById` is only needed for static publishing; when using dynamic publishing, it's ok to use the standard `getElementById`)
3. You're not specifying the express install parameter, so your SWFObject syntax is invalid. Use this instead:

.

```
swfobject.embedSWF(flashname, "myAlternativeContent", "800", "600", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

.

A solution to #1 and #2 is to use SWFObject's `callback` feature. This helps with timing by ensuring you won't invoke your DOM functions until the embed is successful.  It also provides a reference to the embedded `<object>` which enables you to avoid making the `swfobject.getObjectById` call.

```
function flashplayer(flashname) {

    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    params.play = "true";
    params.menu = "true";
    params.scale = "noscale";
    params.allowfullscreen = "true";
    var attributes = {
        id: "flashDiv",
        name: "flashDiv"
    };
    function mycallback(event){
        var obj = event.ref;
        totalFrames = obj.totalFrames;
        $('#duration').html(totalFrames);
        currentFrame1 = obj.currentFrame;
        $('#current').html(currentFrame1);
        obj.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    }
    swfobject.embedSWF(flashname, "myAlternativeContent", "800", "600", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes, mycallback);
}
```

Bear in mind you may still encounter timing issues; SWFObject's callback is invoked as soon as the `<object>` is embedded in the page -- it doesn't mean the SWF has finished loading.

You can check the SWF's loading status by checking Flash Player's `PercentLoaded` method combined with a JavaScript `setInterval`.

```
var obj = event.ref;
if(obj.PercentLoaded() === 100){
    //do stuff
} else {
    //Use setInterval to check PercentLoaded again
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  However when I used  var obj = event.ref;
 I got this error (Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'totalFrames': object is null or undefined).  I changed it to: var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("flashDiv");  I get the total frame but still not the current frame number which is playing.

Comment: That's due to the timing issue I mentioned ta the end of my post; if the SWF hasn't finished loading, you can't query it for TotalFrames. Wrap your query in a conditional statement checking for PercentLoaded. Also, I believe TotalFrames begins with a capital T and is case-sensitive. obj.TotalFrames()  See http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_03.html

Comment: Thanks, your advice worked well; however still could not get the current frame number; also the TotalFrames did not work in FireFox or Chrome.  I found this posting and it worked.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks, your advice worked well; however still could not get the current frame number; also the TotalFrames did not work in FireFox or Chrome.  I found this posting and it worked.  Thanks again for your assistance.