# SWFObject event undefined in Chrome works in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, flash, swfobject

I want to get the currentFrame of my Flash movie when it is loaded. I followed the the tutorial found here http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/index.html and [SWFOBJECT CurrentFrame Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481242/swfobject-currentframe-javascript). I am using SWFObject 2.3 beta. This works perfectly fine on Internet Explorer however it does not work on Google Chrome.

In Chrome I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.ref.currentFrame is not a function
```

Checking `e` it returns `[object Object]`
Checking `e.ref` returns `[object HTMLObjectElement]`
Checking `e.ref.totalFrames` returns `undefined`

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
function mycall(e){
    setInterval(function(){console.log("Frame: " + e.ref.currentFrame)},1000);
}
swfobject.embedSWF("notmyswf.swf", "course", "100%", "100%", "6.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes, mycall);
```

Why is this not working on Chrome but works well with IE? Is the event `e` not detected? Is there a work-around on how to make this work on Chrome?

The purpose of this is for me to create a check if the user is really using the course he has opened and not just leaving it idle. I have already added a code that will check idle but it is not enough. Most learners, have figured out a way to just open a course, leave it there to accumulate hours of training. Some even have a program running in their computers that will just move the mouse 1-pixel every few seconds so that the computer does not go to idle. If I can check the current frame of the Flash movie, I can create a function that will calculate the current page the user is viewing every 15 minutes. If he is stuck in the same page I can then show a prompt that the user must click in order to continue viewing the course or it will automatically close.

Comment: `e.ref` is a reference to the SWF itself. It's cross-browser. When you say "Checking `e.ref.totalFrames` returns `undefined`", at what point are you checking? Inside the `setInterval` or directly in the `mycall` function?

Comment: Also, what happens in Firefox and Safari (if you're on a Mac)?

Comment: One more question. :) Is this a SCORM-based course? Produced by Captivate or Articulate?

Comment: I am checking the `e.ref.totalFrames` and `e.ref.currentFrame()` inside setInterval since at start this value is not available yet until the Flash movie has loaded.

Comment: The course has SCORM functionality support inside and it works great. However, this functionality I am adding is to support a regular PHP webserver that we are using. Essentially, the course has legacy send and load functionalities to save and retrieve data from a MySQL database at the same time, code to send and retrieve data from javascript (I actually used your idea from your site :))

Comment: We are using Flash CS6 and made the entire thing from scratch. This was from 2002 and we had previously migrated from Macromedia Director to Flash. Our company did not know of Captivate or Articulate before. We are now also slowly transitioning to HTML5 using Adobe Edge Animate. Still not Captivate or Articulate.

Comment: Assuming the course is saving a bookmark each time the page/slide advances, place your timer on the calls to the DB instead of checking currentFrame. This keeps it pure JS, and if someone hasn't performed a commit in x number of minutes you can display your warning about inactivity.

Comment: I see. That is a good option. However, I forgot to mention that there also an auto save timer every 3 minutes. So every 3 minute the progress of the user is saved. That is why I was looking for currentFrame so that I can compare it to the previous save's frame. If the previous save's frame is the same to the currentFrame after 15 minutes then the user has not moved from that page for that time and I can then display the "Are your still viewing the course?" message.

Comment: `TypeError: e.ref.currentFrame is not a function` I get the same error on Firefox as with Chrome. IE11 working great. here are some screenshots [link](http://www.fitforbanking.com/images/ie11working.PNG) [link](http://www.fitforbanking.com/images/firefox.PNG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest dropping the SWF-based `currentFrame` approach in favor of monitoring your calls to the database using JavaScript. (Based on your comments, it sounds like the DB calls are being sent by JS, so this shouldn't be a problem.)

If the course bookmark is auto-saved every 3 minutes (as described in your comments), you can cache the value in your page's JS and do a compare every time the save is performed. If the value hasn't changed in x number of minutes, you can display your timeout warning.

If you're using a SCORM wrapper (or similar), this is really simple, just modify the wrapper to include your timer code. Something like:

```
//Old code (pseudocode, not tested)
function setBoomark (val){
    API.SetValue("cmi.core.lesson_location", val);
}
```

---

```
//New code (pseudocode, not tested)
var current_location = "";

var activityTimer;

function disableCourse(){
    //do stuff to disable course because it timed out
}

function setBoomark (val){
    API.SetValue("cmi.core.lesson_location", val);
    if(val === current_location){
        //do nothing, timer keeps ticking
    } else {
        //reset timer using new bookmark value
        if(activityTimer){ clearTimeout(activityTimer); }
        activityTimer = setTimeout(disableCourse, 15000);
        //Update current_location value
        current_location = val;
    }
}
```

This is a rough sketch but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I will try this too. Currently I am using lesson_location for the current page the user is on. I will test this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I feel stupid!

It did not work in Chrome and Firefox because I used the wrong casing for the functions but in IE11 it works no matter the case.

So the correct functions are:

```
e.ref.CurrentFrame() //I used currentFrame() which still works in IE11
e.ref.TotalFrames() //I used totalFrames() which still works in IE11
e.ref.PercentLoaded() //I used this correctly and was able to get the value
```